# sklearn random forest sample_weight in fit()

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

In sklearn's RF fit function (or most fit() functions), one can pass in "sample_weight" parameter to weigh different points. By default all points are equal weighted and if I pass in an array of **1**s as sample_weight, it does match the original model without the parameter.

But if I pass in an array of **0.1**s or **1/len(array)** as sample_weight, it changes the model (predictions are different now), although points are still equally weighted. This is troubling since weight scaling seems to matter. So what's the proper way for scaling so that I have a unique solution?

Example below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
boston = datasets.load_boston()

X = boston.data
y = boston.target

reg = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1, n_estimators=10)
reg.fit(X, y)

reg_eq = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1, n_estimators=10)
reg_eq.fit(X, y, sample_weight=np.full(len(y),1))

reg_eq_bad = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1, n_estimators=10)
reg_eq_bad.fit(X, y, sample_weight=np.full(len(y),0.1))


xt = X[:20]
print(reg.predict(xt))
print(reg_eq.predict(xt))
print(reg_eq_bad.predict(xt))

np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(reg.predict(xt),reg_eq.predict(xt))
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(reg.predict(xt),reg_eq_bad.predict(xt)) # 75% mismatch
```

Comment: The question could really do with a [MCVE], which should be straightforward to make by adapting some example from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the `randomForestRegressor` by a simple `DecisionTreeRegressor` you will find that the predictions are indeed equals.

But with **random forests**, if you trick the input data with the `sample_weight` parameter, nothing ensure that the prediction will remain unchanged because of the randomness/uncertainty introduced by those models.

Although, the difference should not be significant if the model works as it should....

Comment: The randomness you referred to is actually fixed due to the "random_state" parameter. So it should not be the source of differences. Otherwise, why would the reg_eq match the original?

Comment: mmh, yes you maybe right...I tried to use the `DecisionTreeRegressor` with the parameters `splitter="random"`, as it is the splitter actually used by the `RandomForestRegressor`, and it turns out that all predict values are the same with different `sample_weight` (as you expected). So Either the `random_state` is badly propagated during the parallel processing of trees, or I miss something.